# What type of SATA cable should I buy?

Tags: sata, cable, optical-drive

I've bought a new optical drive. It's a Samsung SH-S223C with SATA connection (see the below image). Since it is OEM with no box, no cable came with it, so I need two cables now. Since I have an extra SATA power cable, it's OK, but I have to buy the data cable.

What type of cable should I buy? If you please give a picture of it besides its type as well, I'll be happy. My motherboard is GigaByte P43-ES3G.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A standard (internal) SATA cable should be required, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) has a picture (the required cable is on the **left**):

[image: SATA cables]

This will connect to the one of the yellow SATA ports shown on the bottom left (from GigaByte's webpage for the [GA-P43-ES3G](http://uk.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2960#ov)):

[image: GA-P43-ES3G motherboard]